# Teamviewer and dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, teamviewer

So I'm trying to install an older version of Teamviewer that doesn't require me to every time accept on my host computer. So going with version before, 11. But having a bit of issues when trying to install:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_11.0.67687_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package teamviewer.
(Reading database ... 222321 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack teamviewer_11.0.67687_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer (11.0.67687) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:
teamviewer depends on lib32asound2; however:  
Package lib32asound2 is not installed.
teamviewer depends on ia32-libs; however:
Package ia32-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package teamviewer (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
teamviewer
$
```

So when then trying to install the dependencies myself:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lib32asound2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package lib32asound2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'lib32asound2' has no installation candidate
$
```

I googled a little and was told to do a $apt-get -f install, I did and nothing helped. So wtf is up? Even installing the new version of teamviewer doesn't work either:

```
$ sudo apt-get install teamviewer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
teamviewer is already the newest version (11.0.67687).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
teamviewer : Depends: lib32asound2 but it is not installable
Depends: ia32-libs but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
$
```

^But I *just* did this... -.-

Answer (score 0):

```
xxxx depends on xxxx; however:  
Package xxxx is not installed.
```

This usually means the dependency is not longer available. If you Google `ia32-libs` and `lib32asound2` you can find discussion saying that they are removed.

Back to you problem, you can set the remote computers to Unattended Access so that you don't need to manually accept the connection every time.